# Trying to create file in C with full permissions for all

Tags: c, file, file-permissions

In my code, I have the following fragment:

```
char* filename="/something.txt";
umask(0);
int filehandle=open(filename,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|0x777);
close(filehandle);
```

Upon executing it, the file is created but the permissions are not set correctly even though I followed documentation thoroughly.

Documentation states:

> The  argument  mode  specifies the permissions to use in case a new file is cre-ated.  It is modified by the process's umask in the usual way:  the  permissions of  the  created  file are (mode & ~umask).

and for the mode, I specified 0x777 which means read, write and execute. for umask, I specified zero so `0x777 & ~0` should result in 777.

The permissions that actually result are 670.

Why is that and how do I fix?

Comment: try with open(filename,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0x777); instead of open(filename,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|0x777);

Comment: `int filehandle=open(filename,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|0x777);` is wrong. `mode` is a separate argument for `open()`, and should be `0777` rather than `0x777`.

Comment: ok both suggestions combined worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 13):

For a start, it should be octal `0777` rather than hex `0x777`, the equivalencies are:

```
0x777   0111 0111 0111   011 101 110 111   r-xrw-rwx, plus other stuff(a)
0777    111 111 111          111 111 111   rwxrwxrwx
```

Secondly, the signature is:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

meaning that the mode is a *separate* argument, not something that you `or` with the flags.

Hence the line you're looking for would be:

```
int filehandle = open (filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777);
```

---

(a) I believe POSIX leaves those upper bits unspecified but Linux would use them to indicate that the file was `setgid` and `sticky` (though not in the original sense of sticky meaning code was kept cached in the swap space - Linux has never supported that, instead using the sticky bit to restrict who can perform certain operations on files within a sticky directory).